# trim existing value in mongo documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I currently have some DB in mongoose that has some values that were not trim() initially but now I want to trim all the values. How do I find and trim all the values. Below is an example of the DB and the expected result.

**DB:**

```
[
  {
    "key": "hello "
  },
  {
    "key": "world"
  },
  {
    "key": "test "
  }
]
```

**expected result:**

```
[
  {
    "key": "hello"
  },
  {
    "key": "world"
  },
  {
    "key": "test"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$trim](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trim/) since is possible to use aggregation stages into the update query.

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "key": {
        "$trim": {
          "input": "$key"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9bFPd03r3vS)

Also to do it more efficient you can trim only values which finish with a space using a regular expresion [like this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DD43c7_6pBt). I'm not an expert on regex but `"^.* $"` should match only values with a space at the end.